# how to stop a sound when an animation ends

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-video

I have very little experience in coding in general. But I've somehow managed to get this far with this, and I'm stuck on the very last thing.

This is for a Twitch alert, I'm doing this through 'Stream Elements'

The thing I'm having issues with is stopping the sound once the typing letters have fully appeared, I have no idea how to do this. Is it even possible?

I Forgot to mention, the Typekit links are intentionally broken, as I didn't want to share the link (Since I'm assuming they're all unique and based off your adobe account)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer, fullText, currentOffset, onComplete,  hearbeat = document.getElementById('heartbeat');

    heartbeat.play();
    function Speak(person, text, callback) {
        $("#usernamean-container").html(person);
        fullText = text;
        currentOffset = 0;
        onComplete = callback;
        timer = setInterval(onTick, 120
       );
    }

    function onTick() {
        currentOffset++;
        if (currentOffset == fullText.length) {
            complete();
            return;
        }
        var text = fullText.substring(0, currentOffset);
        $("#message").html(text);
    }
    function complete() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        $("#message").html(fullText);
        onComplete()
        ;
    }

    $(".box").click(function () {
        complete();
    });

    Speak("{{name}}",
        "{{name}} Is now a Witness",
    )
    //get data from the  StreamElements  data injection
    const name = '{{name}}';

    // vanilla es6 query selection (can use libraries and frameworks too)
    const userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#username-container');

    // change the inner html to animate it 
    userNameContainer.innerHTML = stringToAnimatedHTML(name, animation);

    /**
     * return an html, with animation
     * @param s: the text
     * @param anim: the animation to use on the text
     * @returns {string}
     */
    function stringToAnimatedHTML(s, anim) {
        let stringAsArray = s.split('');
        stringAsArray = stringAsArray.map((letter) => {
            return `<span class="animated-letter ${anim}">${letter}</span>`
        });
        return stringAsArray.join('');

    }
    heartbeat.pause();
    heartbeat.currentTime = 0;
});
```

```css
@import url(@import url("https://use.typekit.net/.css");

.awsome-text-container {
    font-family: typeka, sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.image-container {
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}

.text-container {
    font-family: typeka, sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: rgb(204, 10, 33);
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heart" class="heart">
    <audio id="heartbeat" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/135995830279733248/733547597305741332/typewriters.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/.css">
  <div class="text-container">
      <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://media.tenor.com/images/83d6a5ed40a24164dfe1e4e19fad23d9/tenor.gif">
      </div>
      <div>
          <div class="awsome-text-container">
              <span id="message"></span>
              <br>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

I have seen messier code and was therefor disappointed ;-). Regarding your question:

Main problem would be that you have a typo in your code and you call the `heartbeat.pause();` in the `complete` method and not at the end of script (as this would be called independently of the completion of the animation).

Typo:

```
hearbeat = document.getElementById('heartbeat');
```

Changed method:

```
function complete() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    $("#message").html(fullText);
    heartbeat.pause();
    heartbeat.currentTime = 0;
}
```

and remove the lines from the bottom of your script.

Comment: That's a very me thing to have happen haha, THANK YOU SO MUCH! 
By the way, would it be possible to have {{name}} show up in a different colour? How would i go about doing that? O_O

Thank you so much! Sorry for the extra question!

Comment: You are very welcome and great you got it solved! How about wrapping the username in a span like `<span class="username">{{name}}</span> is now a witness` with an additional CSS class like `.username { color: red; }`? Regarding typos: you got another one here: `$("#usernamean-container")` ;-)

Comment: If you want the username to also show up in a different color not only in the text but in the user name container as well, also wrap the username in your `Speak()` routine: `$("#usernamean-container").html('<span class="username">'+person+'</span>');`.